# is it possible to boot an Azure VM with a different bootable iso?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, boot, disaster-recovery

just for a hypothetical case: is it possible to boot a VM in Azure with an ISO file and a different OS? Eg. I have a Windows Server 2016 and want to boot this VM with a Linux?

For instance if the MBR is destroyed or other issues that block the VM from booting and i might be able to fix this with a Linux.

Comment: why the votedown? Would it not be helpful to explain what is incorrect on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to boot a VM in Azure with an ISO file and a different
>   OS?

Unfortunately, for now Azure does **not** support this.

If our windows OS MBR is destroyed or other issues that block the VM from booting, to fix this problem, we should **download** this VM's VHD to local, and use Hyper-V to fix it with ISO file. After completed, we should upload this new VHD to Azure storage account, and use this new VHD to **create Azure VM**(create it with existing Vnet and public IP address, just replace this VHD).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @jason-ye-msft thanks! It is very helpful. Guess I will try it this way. Another option could be to attach the vhd to another linux vm in Azure. I will check if this is working next days.